# How to determine data type from DragEventArgs

Tags: winforms, drag-and-drop

I have implemented drag and drop in my application, but am having some difficulty determining the type of the object being dragged. I have a base class `Indicator` and several classes derived from it. A dragged object could be of any of these types. The code snippet below seems inelegant and is prone to maintenance issues. Every time we add a new derived class, we have to remember to touch this code. It seems like we should be able to use inheritance here somehow.

```
  protected override void OnDragOver(DragEventArgs e)
  {
     base.OnDragOver(e);

     e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;

     // If the drag data is an "Indicator" type
     if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(Indicator)) ||
         e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(IndicatorA)) ||
         e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(IndicatorB)) ||
         e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(IndicatorC)) ||
         e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(IndicatorD)))
     {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
     }
  }
```

Similarly, we have issues using GetData to actually get the dragged object:

```
protected override void OnDragDrop(DragEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnDragDrop(e);

    // Get the dragged indicator from the DragEvent
    Indicator indicator = (Indicator)e.Data.GetData(typeof(Indicator)) ??
                          (Indicator)e.Data.GetData(typeof(IndicatorA)) ??
                          (Indicator)e.Data.GetData(typeof(IndicatorB)) ??
                          (Indicator)e.Data.GetData(typeof(IndicatorC)) ??
                          (Indicator)e.Data.GetData(typeof(IndicatorD));
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Store your data by explicitly specifying the type, i.e.

```
dataObject.SetData(typeof(Indicator), yourIndicator);
```

This will allow you to retrieve it just based on the `Indicator` type, rather than the child type.

Comment: That works like a champ!

To complete your solution:
Inside of OnMouseDown, I used to have:
DoDragDrop(indicator, DragDropEffects.Move);

Now, it looks like this:
DataObject d = new DataObject();
d.SetData(typeof(Indicator), indicator);
DoDragDrop(d, DragDropEffects.Move);

Answer (score 3):

There's the [`IDataObject.GetFormats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1745023c.aspx) method:

> Returns a list of all formats that data stored in this instance is associated with or can be converted to.

It's an array of `String`:

```
String[] allFormats = myDataObject.GetFormats();
```

You could then check that list for your type, one of which should be `Indicator` I would have thought.