# Is there a better way to compare dragged data type?

Tags: c#, winforms, types, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to check whether an object dragged onto a DataGridView is of a specific type. After a lot of messing about, the only way that I could come up with was:

```
if ((e.Data.GetData(dummy.GetType())) != null)
```

where `dummy` is a dummy variable of the type that I am testing for, and `e` is a DragEventArgs object. This seems pretty awkward to me, is there a better way?

Comment: Look at this SO Question and Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150056/how-to-determine-data-type-from-drageventargs

Comment: `e.Data.GetDataPresent` is what you're looking for.

Comment: ah ok, thanks, `if(e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(InstrumentTreeNode)))` seems to be what you're both getting at